# How to convert a soap web-service to accept JSON request

Tags: java, json, web-services, soap

I am trying to convert an existing SOAP web-service to make it to accept JSON request. Due to some very specific requirements we want to switch to JSON.

I did some research regarding this but couldn't find any solution as to how can i do this.

Will it be possible to change existing SOAP web-service to accept JSON request. Can anyone guide me on how can i do this?

Comment: By the way It is not SOAP when you use JSON.

Comment: This is much too broad for StackOverflow.  We cannot educate you on how to do this in the space available, and anyway that would be against the site guidelines.  You do the research and the work and ask a specific question when you run into a problem. Please visit the [help] and read [ask] for more information.